# Not able to get values in html using ngfor ANGULAR

Tags: angular

I have an array and it has all these data stored

```
Form values: {
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "R",
      "lastName": "B",
      "repeat_sun": true,
      "repeat_mon": true,
      "repeat_tue": false,
      "skills": [
        {
          "skill": "JAVA",
          "exp": "2"
        }
      ],
      "userdays": [
        "Sun",
        "Mon"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have stored these values in tempArray
and i am accessing it in my html

template

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">first name</th>
            <th scope="col">last name</th>
            <th scope="col">skill and exp</th>
            <th scope="col">days</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr
       *ngFor="let details of tempArray"
                id="{{ details.empIndex }}">
            <td> {{ details.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ details.lastName }}</td>
            <td>  <span *ngFor="let data of details.skills">
                    {{ data.skill }} and {{ data.exp }},
                    <br />
                  </span>
            </td>

            <td> <span *ngFor="let data of details.userdays">
                    {{ details.userdays}}
                    <br />
                  </span>
           </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am able to display all the values, but userdays...I need to display userdays vals

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdfeqs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't adding the users to the final array:

```
private mapFormEmployee(
empIndex: number
): {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
repeat_sun: boolean;
repeat_mon: boolean;
repeat_tue: boolean;
skills: { skill: string; exp: string }[];
userdays: []. // <---- this was missing
} {
const employeeFormGroup = this.employees().at(empIndex);

return {
  firstName: employeeFormGroup.get("firstName").value,
  lastName: employeeFormGroup.get("lastName").value,
  repeat_sun: employeeFormGroup.get("repeat_sun").value,
  repeat_mon: employeeFormGroup.get("repeat_mon").value,
  repeat_tue: employeeFormGroup.get("repeat_tue").value,
  skills: employeeFormGroup
    .get("skills")
    .value.map((_, skillIndex) => this.mapFormSkill(empIndex, skillIndex)),
  userdays: employeeFormGroup.get("userdays").value // <--- and this
};
```

}

And then output it:

```
<td> <span *ngFor="let data of details.userdays;let i = index;">
     {{ data }}
     <br />
</span></td>
```

Comment: I followed this, but still not getting an ouput, you can check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdfeqs

Comment: I made corrections and I am getting the result now https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdfeqs

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is how your array is saved. There is no userdays on your array. userdays are saved as flat.

Comment: I made corrections and I am getting the result now https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdfeqs

Comment: Great. Reward please.